# change a class field value which is run by a thread

Tags: java, servlets

I have a thread which runs in the background. This thread has a `HashMap` which holds the user id and `HttpServletResponse` object. When the user logged out then that entry from the map should be deleted. My question is how can I access that map from another servlet?

Comment: Assuming this application is running in a Java web container (Tomcat, JBoss, etc), why aren't you storing this data in the user's session?  Then the session just needs to be destroyed during the logout process.  Otherwise you will need to provide a mechanism to get a reference to the HashMap in question.

Comment: In my case, session is not useful, because that thread is for all user

Answer (score 0):

Re:"My question is how can I access that map from another servlet?", you can use ServletContext or Application scope to share the data between servlets running in a servlet container.